Problem with web scraping in R (rvest) and SelectorGadget. Error character(0)
I am trying to scrape data from https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/jacouchs/marketing-budget-and-actual-sales-dataset with using rvest and SelectorGadget. There is a table with 222 rows and 2 columns in that link. I need to assign each columns to different variables.
Here is what I have done:
# install.packages("rvest")
# install.packages("dplyr")

library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link = "https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/jacouchs/marketing-budget-and-actual-sales-dataset"
page = read_html(link)

marketing_budget = page %>% html_nodes(".bPYkVN div:nth-child(1)")%>% html_text()
print(marketing_budget)

The output is character(0) however my expectation was that the variable would take the all 222 values.
Is there anyone who can help me with this? Thank you in advance!
I'm sorry if there is any problem with the question I asked or any obvious mistake with my code. I'm a begginer. I am also open to any advice!

Table you are looking for is not within the page source, it's pulled and rendered by Javascript that gets executed by your browser;  with read_html() you'd only get actual page source, js will not be evaluated. You can use rvest::read_html_live() or other headless browser options;  or mimc javascript calls that are fetching that preview table data. But it takes a lot less time and effort to just create a Kaggle account and download that dataset with a single click. If it must be automated, you can use Kaggle API.  So perhaps explain why you think it would be a good idea in the first place?

If it's just for practice, start with some content that would also render without javascript, i.e. disable js for a specific site and check if the the table is still visible in the browser.

You can use the API behind the site.
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)

cookies = c(
  `ka_sessionid` = "451fd57b37420ec1e12752f641751e2c",
  `_ga_T7QHS60L4Q` = "GS1.1.1716874446.3.1.1716874528.0.0.0",
  `_ga` = "GA1.1.1156449516.1714279309",
  `ACCEPTED_COOKIES` = "true",
  `CSRF-TOKEN` = "CfDJ8C7919k9hp5Hq9pDr-pvzJo0YoYVuV4B8-HYu6l9DnUX_uPn4qcLLK8m5PnvCISNjVgET2285U7zYIDuYkQv3WcFmjJZhSESVZRJ8B3tDA",
  `XSRF-TOKEN` = "CfDJ8C7919k9hp5Hq9pDr-pvzJr-goMjc10reHohzKZi-G6mMTNKK0QN8Cu67RdutzyEBz-qvio9YH4oqvDaCzXTj9kRnHqt669dlbSC4IEJAdnveA",
  `CLIENT-TOKEN` = "eyJhbGciOiJub25lIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.",
  `recaptcha-ca-t` = "AaGzOmd8gDEwvpH-HAFi7d5WTB0YDnhu2W8JlMlQbzwISn-vre6A1QV3ysbcnyz4tou6PktDIZWHqMYf3Kig8-SOcjbVIHrlUbIzTMWcrHMxYVKW--oDMY0TwxAQAgrZ88Xeqd4BkVWfsRs:U=bc304e08a0000000"
)

headers = c(
  `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0",
  `Accept` = "application/json",
  `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.5",
  `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate, br",
  `content-type` = "application/json",
  `x-xsrf-token` = "CfDJ8C7919k9hp5Hq9pDr-pvzJr-goMjc10reHohzKZi-G6mMTNKK0QN8Cu67RdutzyEBz-qvio9YH4oqvDaCzXTj9kRnHqt669dlbSC4IEJAdnveA"
)

data = '{"verificationInfo":{"datasetId":2231405,"databundleVersionId":3786453},"firestorePath":"pIMnn9p2Sky87SJGFYyL/versions/6lHzXXVZfin9SfHfmEqP/files/sales_dataset.csv","tableQuery":{"skip":0,"take":225,"filter":{"constantFilter":{"value":true}},"selectedColumns":[],"sorts":[]}}'

res <- httr::POST(
  url = "https://www.kaggle.com/api/i/datasets.DatasetService/GetDataViewExternal",
  httr::add_headers(.headers=headers),
  httr::set_cookies(.cookies = cookies),
  body = data
)

table <- content(res)$dataView$dataTable$rows |>
  map(function(row) {
    data.frame(row$text) %>%
      setNames(c("budget", "sales"))
  }) |>
  list_rbind()

Here are the results:
> head(table)
  budget sales
1 187.86 12.14
2 138.13 12.33
3 177.89  8.41
4 181.13   8.9
5  151.5 12.57
6 106.87  11.3

You could probably trim out a few of the cookies and headers. Also those tokens might expire, in which case you'd need to get new ones.
Agree with the comment: will probably be a lot simpler to just download the CSV file.

map_dfr was superseded in 1.0.0 and shouldn't be used - see the docs for alternatives.

Answer updated to not use deprecated map_dfr() as suggested by @Spacedman.
